# Spring: check for standard query params on every endpoint

Tags: java, spring, filtering

We have a set of endpoints in Spring and for every single one, we could like to ask the user to include a security key and token, etc. For example:

```
/endpoint?key=asdf&token=1234
```

However, we don't want to have to rewrite every single endpoint. Is there an easy way to intercept every call, check the params, and then pass on to the regular code?

Comment: Use a filter or interceptor? Only forward to the regular code if the token is valid.

Comment: I've tried to look up information on filters, but I don't understand how they work. Are there any good references out there?

Answer (score 2):

Spring has concept of interceptor where you can pre process the request before passing on to appropriate controller. You can define your own interceptor implementing HandleInterceptor or extending HandlerInterceptorAdapter Take a look at this: http://java.dzone.com/articles/using-spring-interceptors-your

Comment: I believe @Jason is using spring web service. Is it the same setup as for spring mvc?

Comment: I haven't used Spring Webservices but there is an EndpointInterceptor interface which has method handleRequest.